# Why do .bat scripts get locked after execution in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch, gvim

Ever since I moved to Windows 7, whenever I am am developing a .bat script I have exactly one chance to get it right. As soon as I execute the script, it becomes locked by an unknown process even if the execution appears to have completed, and I have to force quit explorer or restart to be able to edit the .bat file again.

For example, if I create a .bat file,

```
@echo off
@start prog\ConsolePortable\ConsolePortable.exe
```

then realize after executing it that I needed to change some aspect of the script,

```
@echo off
@cd prog\ConsolePortable
@start ConsolePortable.exe
```

Then I will not be able to save my changes. For example, in gvim I get the message, "'console.bat' is read-only (add ! to override)," and then when I try to override, I get the message, "E212: Can't open file for writing."

Surely there must be some way of scripting without requiring [ProcessExplorer](https://superuser.com/questions/208397/how-to-stop-a-bat-process-on-windows) on every computer I use. How does one find the process of a .bat file to stop it, anyway? I tried ProcessExplorer and BSOD'd the compy trying to stop it. I have also tried using cmd /c in place of start.

EDIT: 
ConsolePortable starts fine here and appears to exit fine, however the following test setup does not freeze the editor:

```
// Program.java
class Program {public static void main(String[] args) {System.exit(0);}}

// startProgram.bat 
echo Starting Program in Java ...
start java Program
echo exiting bat file ...
```

EDIT 2: 
Perhaps I should mention that I created the file by using the touch command in cygwin. After restarting the computer, I can't duplicate this problem, though I have encountered it on other computers before.

Comment: Do you test the batch file in a fresh `cmd` window?  I'm not exactly sure what the syntax would be, but you could add a command at the end of the .bat to spawn a fresh `cmd` window (for the next run) and kill the old one, which should free up the file.

Comment: I had not tried that; I had been double clicking on it. I will try that ...

Comment: I would be looking at your "ConsolePortable.exe" program and make sure that it is exiting properly.  Also, have a look at [Why won't cmd exit after execution of batch file?](http://superuser.com/questions/192550/why-wont-cmd-exit-after-execution-of-batch-file)

Comment: Where are you saving the .bat files to?  If it's in a sub-folder of Program Files, Win7 doesn't allow editing by default.  I have had it, on occasion, allow me to add new files, but not save or edit existing files in those folders.

Comment: @Mokubai I have had a look at that link; misterjaytee recommends using start as above. How do I make sure an .exe is exiting properly? Is there an error log somewhere?

Comment: That's what I thought `start` should be doing, but it appears that in this case there is something weird going on and that program is the only thing that could be doing it.

Comment: You can use aforementioned Process Explorer to find out which process locks your .bat file (Menu|Find|Find a Handle or DLL command or simply press Ctrl+F and type in the name of your script). Then it should be clearer what to do. One thing I can tell at the moment is that cmd.exe itself does *not* lock .bat/.cmd files it executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is possibly an error with your editor, or you have weird permissions set up.

I quite often edit batch files with notepad (whilst running) and have not had a problem.

However, I am not sure you can just inject commands - it remembers the line number (I think) that it was on.

e.g. in your bat file, after starting, it will have finished processing.

Place a pause at the third line, then run but do not press a key after the pause. Edit the original bat file, place a command in the fourth line - and you will see that the fourth line will get processed.

Comment: You think this is a problem with vanilla win32 gvim? What do you mean by "inject commands ...  in your bat file, after starting, it will of finished processing?"

Comment: I know this is OLD and this is not the English site, but I have to point out "it will of" is probably meant to be "it will've" or "it will have".

Answer (score 2):

I would try changing the line

```
@start ConsolePortable.exe
```

To

```
@start "myProgram" ConsolePortable.exe
```

As from http://ss64.com/nt/start.html:

> START "title" [/Dpath] [options] "command" [parameters]
>
> Notes:
>
> Always include a TITLE this can be a
>   simple string like "My Script" or just
>   a pair of empty quotes "" According to
>   the Microsoft documentation, the title
>   is optional, but you may have problems
>   if it is omitted.
>
> Document files may be invoked through
>   their file association just by typing
>   the name of the file as a command.
>   e.g. START "" WORD.DOC would launch
>   the application associated with the
>   .DOC file extension

This one caught me off guard when I tried to script VLC some time ago and putting a title in there fixed a seemingly related issue for me.

Comment: You should always pass a title (empty or otherwise) to the `start` command unless you are absolutely, positively, 100% certain that the resulting command line will not contain any quotes.  As the `start` help mentions: The first quoted parameter is assumed to be the title, no matter where it appears.